# Three Tables, Two Joins, Only One Table Needed For Results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got three tables: Clients, Services, and Client Locations.  I'm running a query that needs to return the locations of clients that received a certain service.  So using the second table in the SELECT and the third table in the WHERE.  I'm using two LEFT JOINs and getting my results repeated in an undesirable way.

Here are simplified versions of the three tables...

**Clients (clients)**

```
id_client | clientName
----------------------
1         | Abby
2         | Betty
3         | Cathy
```

**Client Services (services)**  Used only in the WHERE statement

```
id_client | date      | serviceType
-----------------------------------
1         | 1/5/2015  | Counseling
1         | 1/12/2015 | Counseling
1         | 1/19/2015 | Counseling
2         | 1/21/2015 | Sup. Group
```

**Client Locations (locations)**  Used only in the SELECT statement

```
id_client | city
----------------------
1         | Boston, MA
3         | Providence, RI
```

**Here's The Query**

```
SELECT clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
```

**The Results**

```
clientName | city
-----------------------
Abby       | Boston, MA
Abby       | Boston, MA
Abby       | Boston, MA
```

So it's giving me Abby living in Boston three times instead of the desired one.

Now, I know exactly why this is happening.  The LEFT JOIN used for the services table is being used for the results and Abby's three counseling sessions are causing the city to be repeated three times.

Is there another way to do this JOIN so that the services table doesn't cause repetition like this?  I've tried INNER JOIN and get the same thing.

Comment: You should note that your query is using a left join on services with a condition in the where clause which basically makes it an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT c.clientName, l.city
FROM clients c JOIN
     locations l
     ON c.id_client = l.id_client
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM services s
              WHERE c.id_client = s.id_client AND
                    s.serviceType = 'Counseling'
             );
```

Although you can use `group by` or `distinct`, this method should perform better.  There is no need to generate the duplicated results just to remove them in another step.

Comment: I feel like this answer was the best because it solves the problem that I posted in the most efficient manner.   Unfortunately my actual situation is much more complicated than what I posted and this would be a nightmare to implement.

Comment: A correlated subquery performs better? Even better than my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28456160/40822

Comment: It's hard for me to really know performance differences here.  I upvoted yours for providing another way of doing it.  In the end they were all valid solutions for what I posted, but I ended up having to do something slightly different to apply to my actual problem.

Comment: @dotjoe . . . I would expect the correlated subquery to perform better than a subquery with an explicit `select distinct` subquery.  I would expect it to be much, much faster with the appropriate index on `services(id_client, service_type)`.

Comment: interesting, I guess I always thought it would be slower since it has to run the exists for each id_client. Maybe it optimizes that away?

Comment: There are many ways to implement an `exist` -- but MySQL (with an index) will basically just do an index lookup.  That is a pretty fast operation.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
```

Or a `group by`

```
SELECT clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
GROUP BY clients.clientName,locations.city
```

Or a subquery

```
SELECT clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_client, serviceType 
  FROM services 
  GROUP BY id_client, serviceType 
) services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
GROUP BY clients.clientName,locations.city
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda56c/1)

Comment: At first I felt like this wouldn't work because there WOULD be situations where one person would have the same location twice and that would need to be reflected in the results and not boiled down to just one.  But then I realized that I could use a GROUP BY and Group the id_client and id_location column (which, I know I didn't show in my post) and I would get the results I'm looking for.  Wish I could make two answers be the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distinct client ids for that serviceType and then join to client and location to get more details on the client.

```
SELECT clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM 
(Select distinct id_client from services WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling') s
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id_client = s.id_client
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
```

Answer (score 0):

You are summarizing a detail result set. So do that using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT clients.clientName, locations.city
  FROM clients
  LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
  LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
 WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
```

Or use a GROUP BY query and provide some summary statistics:

```
SELECT DISTINCT clients.clientName, locations.city,
       COUNT(*) service_count
  FROM clients
  LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
  LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
 WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling' 
 GROUP BY clients.clientName, locations.city
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use a distinct clause to avoid getting double results.

```
SELECT distinct clients.clientName,locations.city
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
LEFT JOIN services ON clients.id_client=services.id_client
WHERE services.serviceType='Counseling'
```